# Application crashes while pressing NEXT button : Android

Tags: android

I am very beginner in android. i am simply trying to make a small application. it contains pictures. when i press on NEXT button so my application crashes. English language is not my native language so i have tried to elaborate my problem. thanks in advance.

**my xml code here:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_shapes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle1" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnNextShape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
public class Shapes extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    int a = 0;
    ImageView iv;   
    Button btn_next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.maths_shapes);

        btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextShape);
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_shapes);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btnNextShape:
            if (a < 2)
            {
            a++;
            setPage();
            }
            break;    
        }//switch ends
    }//onClick ends


    private void setPage()
    {
        if (a == 0)
        {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.square1);

        }

        if(a == 1)
        {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.rectangle1);
        }

    }//setPage ends
}//class ends
```

Comment: Post your logcat from the crash.

Comment: here is logcat from the crash...

Comment: Where? Please update your post to include it and not in the comments

Comment: if I was a betting man, looking at your code I'd assume the ImageView isn't being found for some reason and you're getting a NullPointerException when iv.setImageResource is being called. But until you update your question with the stack trace, I cannot be sure.

Comment: @MattC With all respect sir, I will bet any drawable resource is not present. :D

Comment: @twntee Or that. I always bet on NullPointerExceptions when it comes to java ;)

Comment: The `ImageView` has the correct `id` as what is in the xml and the `Button` doesn't cause a crash, otherwise I would also assume that the `ImageView` was `null`

Comment: thanks codeMagic for your precious advices

Comment: Sure but where's the logcat?

Comment: I'm thankful to all respectable

Comment: Naveed post the solution yourself, or do try to explain how you solved it, it helps future visitors. :)

Comment: As i'm a very very new beginner so i was also having 04 radio buttons in my application so they were creating problems so i did remove them all from xml and and as well java codes so problem was solved....anyway i taught a lot from those who gave very very precious advises on commenting here

Comment: I'm always afraid that someone would down vote so i try my best to specify a question...i'm at very initial stage of learning ANDROID so can't handle even very little issues...anyway thanks to all...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to put the picture in your ImageView

```
 iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.square1));
```